# Calculate sum of SVD components

Tags: python, numpy, svd

We now that `A_(m x n) = U_(m x k) * S_(k x k)  * V_(k x n)^T = u_(1) * s_1 * v_(1) + u_(2) * s_2 * v_(2) + ...,` , where `u_(i)` and `v(i)` are i-th columns of `U` and `V`, s_i - i-th diagonal element of S. I am trying to get an array a without using loops, where `a[i] = u_(1) * s_1 * v_(1) + u_(2) * s_2 * v_(2) + ... + u_(i) * s_i * v_(i).` What should i do next?

```
from numpy.linalg import svd

U, S, VT = svd(A, full_matrices=False)
A_1 = U[:, 0:1] * S[0] @ VT[0:1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way would be `einsum`:

```
A_ = np.einsum("ij,j,jk->jik",U[:,:len(VT)],S,VT[:len(U)]).cumsum(0)
```

If as you have wisely done `svd` was called with `full_matrices=False` this simplifies to

```
A_ = np.einsum("ij,j,jk->jik",U,S,VT).cumsum(0)
```

Your `A_1` would correspond to `A_[0]` etc., `A_[-1]` is (up to roundup) the original array `A`.

P.S.: Essentially the same without `einsum`:

```
A_ = ((U*S).T[:,:,None]*VT[:,None,:]).cumsum(0)
```